Faster implementation with Mathematica for these p,q-analog functions
I have implemented some p-q analogue functions in Mathematica.
Clear["Global`*"];
Off[Power::indet];(*Supress 0^0 warnings*)
Unprotect[Power];
Power[0 | 0., 0 | 0.] = 1;
Protect[Power];

PQInteger[n_, 1, 1] := n;
PQInteger[n_, p_, q_] := (p^n - q^n)/(p - q);
PQFactorial[n_, p_, q_] := Product[PQInteger[k, p, q], {k, 1, n}];
PQBinomial[n_, k_, p_, q_] /; 0 <= k <= n := 
  PQFactorial[n, p, q]/(PQFactorial[n - k, p, q]*PQFactorial[k, p, q]);
PQBinomial[6, 3, p, q] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify // Expand
PQDerivative[f_, x_, p_, q_] := (f[p*x] - f[q*x])/((p - q)*x);
PQDerivativePlus[f_, x_, p_, 
   q_] := (f[(q^-1)*x] - f[(p^-1)*x])/((p - q)*x);
PQIntegrateForxFrom0ToInf[f_, p_, q_] := (p - q)*
   Sum[q^j/(p^(j + 1))*f[q^j/(p^(j + 1))], {j, -Infinity, Infinity}];
PQIntegrateForxFrom0Tob[f_, p_, q_, b_] := (p - q)*b*
  Sum[q^j/(p^(j + 1))*f[q^j/(p^(j + 1))*b], {j, 0, Infinity}]
Assuming[{0 < q < p <= 1, n > 0}, 
 FullSimplify[
  PQIntegrateForxFrom0Tob[#^n &, p, q, a] - 
   a^(n + 1)/PQInteger[n + 1, p, q]]]
PQLowerCaseExp[x_, p_, q_] := 
 Sum[p^Binomial[n, 2]*x^n/(PQFactorial[n, p, q]), {n, 0, Infinity}]
PQUpperCaseExp[x_, p_, q_] := 
 Sum[q^Binomial[n, 2]*x^n/(PQFactorial[n, p, q]), {n, 0, Infinity}]
PQPowerNofaminusb[p_, q_, baseA_, baseB_, n_] := 
  Product[(baseA*p^(i - 1) - baseB*q^(i - 1)), {i, 1, n}];
PQPowerNofaplusb[p_, q_, baseA_, baseB_, n_] := 
  Product[(baseA*p^(i - 1) + baseB*q^(i - 1)), {i, 1, n}];
PQBeta[m_, n_, p_, q_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   f = Function[t, t^(m - 1)/(PQPowerNofaplusb[p, q, 1, p*t, m + n])];
    PQIntegrateForxFrom0ToInf[f, p, q]];
PQBaskakovBasisFunction[x_, n_, k_, p_, q_] := 
  PQBinomial[n + k - 1, k, p, q]*p^(k + n*(n - 1)/2)*q^(k*(k - 1)/2)*
   x^k/PQPowerNofaplusb[p, q, 1, x, n + k];
PQBaskakov[f_, n_, p_, q_] := 
 Module[{}, 
  Sum[PQBaskakovBasisFunction[x, n, k, p, q]*
    f[(p^(n - 1)*PQInteger[k, p, q])/(q^(k - 1)*
        PQInteger[n, p, q])], {k, 0, Infinity}]]
PQBaskakov[Exp, 3, 4, 5]
PQFubiniPolynomial[n_, x_, y_, z_, p_, q_] := 
  Coefficient[
    1/(1 - z*PQLowerCaseExp[t, p, q] - 1)*PQLowerCaseExp[x*t, p, q]*
     PQUpperCaseExp[y*t, p, q], t, n]*PQFactorial[n, p, q];
PQFubiniNumber[n_, p_, q_] := PQFubiniPolynomial[n, 0, 0, 1, p, q];
Table[PQFubiniNumber[n, 1, 1], {n, 1, 10}] (* how to fix it? *)
PQApostolTypeBernoulliPolynomial[α_, x_, y_, λ_, p_, q_] := 
  Coefficient[(z/(λ*PQLowerCaseExp[z, p, q] - 1))^α*PQLowerCaseExp[x*z, p, q]* PQUpperCaseExp[y*z, p, q], z, n]*PQFactorial[n, p, q];
PQApostolTypeEulerPolynomial[α_, x_, y_, λ_, p_, q_] := 
  Coefficient[(2/(λ*PQLowerCaseExp[z, p, q] + 1))^α* PQLowerCaseExp[x*z, p, q]*PQUpperCaseExp[y*z, p, q], z, n]* PQFactorial[n, p, q];
PQApostolTypeGenocchiPolynomial[α_, x_, y_, λ_, p_, q_] :=
  Coefficient[(2*z/(λ*PQLowerCaseExp[z, p, q] + 1))^α*PQLowerCaseExp[x*z, p, q]*PQUpperCaseExp[y*z, p, q], z, n]*PQFactorial[n, p, q];

References

APPROXIMATION BY (p, q)-BASKAKOV-BETA OPERATORS
(p,q)-analogue of the Natural Transform with applications
Apostol Type (p,q)-Bernoulli, (p,q)-Euler and
(p,q)-Genocchi Polynomials and Numbers


My question is:
In addition to these, can you give some practical PQFunctions and corresponding Mathematica implementations? Can you give a faster implementation with Mathematica?
Any help would be appreciated.

To be honest I stopped reading at Power[0 | 0., 0 | 0.] = 1;, suspecting that whatever follows makes little sense.

@Roman There were some "experts" in the past who stopped reading Cantor's papers once they encountered infinite set. For example Limit[x^x, x -> 0] == 1 or Limit[0^x, x -> 0, Direction -> -1] == 0. If 0^0==1 is what makes OP's formulas correct there is noting wrong in using it. Though maybe there are better methods than modifying Power .

The point about (not) changing Power has nothing to do with one's views of 0^0.

@DanielLichtblau The point about one's views of 0^0 has nothing to do with OP's question.

@azerbajdzan No argument from me. It’s the alteration of a basic arithmetic function, Power, that matters.
